# Replacing Windows 10

Tags: system-installation

I bought a brand new Lenovo Flex 5 in June and for the first two months it worked like a dream with Windows 10 which came pre-installed.

During the last few months the computer had several occurences of "Blue Screen of Death"

I really do not think this is a hardware problem.

My question is, can Linux replace Windows 10 on my laptop completely or do I have to keep it?

I await your guidance before I delve deeper and engage my husband to help me with the transition.

Comment: Ubuntu *can* replace Windows in your computer, but the larger questions are going to be *"Does the Linux community have all of the programs I want?"*  I run Ubuntu as my primary OS, and do maintain Windows in a Virtual Machine environment for a single program (quickbooks) which is not available for Linux at this time.

Comment: I was too windows user. No switched to ubuntu. Personally, I face less problem now. Only problem is that if you are addicted user of windows os., it will take some time to adjust. If you know well how to configure linux os, you can scrap windows as I did. Most of the windows application works well in Linux in wineHQ, PlaywithLinux, etc. No worries about lose of favourite softwares.

Comment: I'd suggest to [edit] your question, and define your needs from the computer (surf the internet, use microsoft excel, run 3D games, use specific software, etc)

Comment: Linux is not a drop in replacement for windows and in general you can not run your windows apps on Linux. By far the 2  most common barriers with converting to linux are hardware compatibility and software. The first is solved by purchasing a computer with Linux pre-installed rather than Windows.The second problem is there is some windows only application you can not live without . Most common are games and professional grade software.

Comment: I love Linux but some drivers are not working on my Laptop. So I have Linux in a VM on windows and this works fine ;) so whenever I need Linux I start the VM. Thought it might be a solution as well for someone

Comment: TBH and going against the general tone here, **don't!**. At the first hurdle in Windows 10 the first thing you considered was changing OS and not troubleshooting?!? What else will you choose at your first hurdle in Ubuntu (the first of many), "hackintosh", Android x86, Unix, OpenBSD, ... ? **The fact is the BSODs can be hardware related and no OS will fix that.**

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you *can* completely replace Win10 (actually it would be easier than dual-booting), but **before you completely jump ship, I suggest you try running off of a live USB or DVD to make sure that all the hardware in your computer works under Linux.**

In particular, the touchscreen and automatic screen rotation when the display is rotated may or may not work. I would also check to make sure the battery doesn't drain way faster than it should. (The kernel can sometimes force the CPU to run at the highest frequency even when it isn't needed)

But that way, you can try it without making any changes whatsoever to your computer.

---

Also, keep in mind that Windows software will not run natively in Linux. There is a lot of software for Linux, though. For example, Google Chrome is available for Linux, as well as Libreoffice (a free alternative to MS office). There is a compatibility layer called WINE that will allow you to run *some* Windows software, but it is quite buggy and not a great experience.

Assuming that you're not a power user though, and you mostly just use the web browser and email, you shouldn't have any problem with finding Linux software.

---

Overall though, if you're OK with not being able to run Windows software, I think you will find that Linux is a lot more stable than Widnows. You don't have to reboot once a week. Some servers can even run for years before they are rebooted, and even then only rebooted to apply critical security patches.

As an added bonus - you don't really need antivirus for Linux :)

(Sure, there is Linux malware, but any software you install through `apt` is scanned and is basically guaranteed to be safe, and you could always audit the source code if you wanted :D)

Comment: Thank you for the prompt responses everyone. It will all be helpful in making my decision. Cheers and have a wonderful day.